# Difference between Hillshading and Terrain Resource Information Management

Tags: geology, geography, remote-sensing, mapping, gis

I am picking up on remote sensing. I came across a paper where they use the shaded relief model from Terrain Resource Information Management (TRIM) for hillshading. However, is it the same as the hillshade function that can be applied to the DEM in QGIS/ArcGIS?
If I have the images from the two methods (TRIM and GIS), would i be looking at the same images?

Your reply will be appreciated.

Comment: Not an expert (maybe it would be a better match at the GIS Stack Exchange?), but with a GIS hillshade function you need two parameters: Sun azimuth (0—360°) and Sun altitude (0—90°). Each combination of parameters yields a different result; a DEM illuminated from the west will look very different than the same DEM illuminated from the east. So the images will be the same only if the light source parameters are the same.

Comment: Uh, okay. so it is the same image, provided the initial parameters (azimuth and altitude are same.
Thank you.